# How to parse varchar to actual time value?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to insert the data into the final table in snowflake from  the staging table.  When the command is run it give the error:

> Can't parse '20211101132344205550' as timestamp with format 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS.FF'

My table definition and insert statement is here.

I used the same kind of method last time it worked. Thank you so much in advance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE dw.tb_fidctp_order(
sysdate DATE,
record_id NUMBER(18,0) ,
timestamp TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
<trim_excess>
);



INSERT INTO dw.tb_fidctp_order(
    sysdate, 
    record_id, 
    timestamp,
<trim_excess>
    )
 SELECT 
     TO_DATE(LEFT(timestamp, 8), 'YYYYMMDD')
    ,CAST(record_id AS NUMBER(18,0))
    ,TO_TIMESTAMP(LEFT(timestamp,24),'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS.FF') 
<trim_excess>
 FROM stg.tb_fidctp_order_input;
```

Comment: Don't you think a small sample would be better ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with the emphasis on *minimal*.

Comment: Yeah. Not even bothering to read it if you can not be bothered to make an example that is according to the site rules. SMALL and only showing the necessary elements. Even the update - not sure how BID_PRICE_NUMBER is relevant to this question.

Comment: Also last time I checked SQL Server <> Snowflake - please correct your tags.

Comment: well clearly  "'20211101132344205550' " is not in 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS.FF' format

Comment: I am so sorry for the trouble. i will give you minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake you need to define what your format is.  So, if all of your timestamps are formatted as a straight string like that, then you are defining it incorrectly.  Try something more like this:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(left(EXPIRY_DATETIME,24),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF');
```

The `to_timestamp()` function is defining how the input string is formatted, not how you want the timestamp to be formatted as an output.

Answer (score 0):

So the error message is the critical point, your formating string for timestamps have space and `:` time formatting, which needs to be removed.

Below I have used the `tru_to_timestamp` function because it returns NULL istead of erroring with is helpful to show the problem is your formatting:

```
SELECT 
    '20211101132344205550' AS a
    ,try_to_timestamp(a, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS.FF') as b
    ,try_to_timestamp(a, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF') as c;
```

gives:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20211101132344205550 |  | 2021-11-01 13:23:44.205 |

which shows your `,TO_TIMESTAMP(LEFT(timestamp,24),'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS.FF')` 
should be:

```
,TO_TIMESTAMP(LEFT(timestamp,24),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF')
```

and then you would have no problem.